# Using $and when querying nested mongo document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have mongoose schema like this:

```
let message = new Schema({
    text      : String,
    idOnSource: String,
    sourceName: String,
    selections: [
        {
            id: Schema.ObjectId,
            ratingInSelection: Number,
            _id: false
        }
    ],
    ownerIdOnSource: String,
    createdAt : {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

It can be seen that each message belongs to many selections and each message has a rating in each selection.
 1- First I want to know, how can I build a query to find 10 max ratingInSelection given a "selection.id"? In other words 10 max ranked messages for each selection along with rankingInSelection numbers?

2- How can I skip those 10 and get next 10 ranked below those?

Comment: Sorry, maybe the "$and" is misleading in question title :)

Comment: It seems I was not clear enough. Each message belongs to many selections (something like category), and in each selection (category) a message has rating which is denoted by ratingInSelection. I want to query for top ranked messages for one selection (category) which I have its id. I want to prune any data that is not related to previously mentioned selection (category). Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Perhaps you should include a small data sample and what you expect as output as this still reads a little unlclear to me. Also use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35297242/edit) link on your question for more details. Comments should be for adressing responses to people, largely based on you editing your "question" to clarify points that may be unlclear/misunderstood. For example your comment above was made after but not directly to the person who attempted to answer, so unless they come looking for your question ( unlikely ) then they have no idea of your input.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have any idea about your concept but with the little understanding of your need. Try this:

```
  db.collection_name.aggregate(
  [
    {$match:{"ratingInSelection":{$gt:10}}},
    {$limit:4},
    {$sort:{"ratingInSelection":1}},
    {$skip:10}
  ]);
```

**Note:**  Here i am using sorting but i must say sorting in huge database is a worst option.
**$skip**: for ignoring first records
**$limit**: no. of documents to return
**$sort**: on field *ratingInSelection* where 1 specifies ascending sort
**$gt**: for greater than